# What is the most straight-forward way to use Ember.js for just one part of a Rails app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js, frontend

I'd like to develop a Rails app with a full admin suite, authentication, authorization etc. that is pure Rails, but I would like there to be one part of the app that is 'real-time' and where the view is bound to the data, and I'd like to use Ember for this.

For example, I have a `Company` model, which `has_many Parties`, and `Party has_many Guests`. I would like a `User` to be able to log in, navigate to a `Company` page that they are authorized to access, and click a link to `Company/:id/Party/:id/live`, which would be a page featuring an Ember.js app that offers details of all of the `Guests` in the party. It would query the database every X seconds, and the Ember.js app would automatically reflect the updated data (e.g. one section of the page only shows `Guests where Guest.status == in_attendance` or something like this).

So my question is: Is there any standardized or proven way of incorporating Ember into just a portion of a Rails app in this manner?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen [ember-rails](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails)?

Comment: @Beerlington, yes I've played around with ember-rails, but it seems like it is designed to create a full Ember-based single page app with a rails backend. I am looking for something that lets you build a full rails app with one small ember part. I think a key difference is that what I'm picturing may not require using an Ember router, and this is where I get a little lost. Does ember-rails still work in this scenario? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To embed Ember application, you should do two things:

1. Change root element from `body` to something else
2. Disable URL management

Code samples:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  rootElement: '#app'
});

App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: 'none'
});
```

I took this information from Ember Guides: [Embedding Applications](http://emberjs.com/guides/configuring-ember/embedding-applications/)

Comment: Thanks! I got this far, and I have the ember app up and running on a specific page of the rails app. Will I still be able to use ember-data or something similar to link the view to the database via rails? Do you know of any tutorials that touch on this?

Comment: Ember Data serializes data in the way, it can be consumed by Rails controller, no problem. Try this tutorial, it touches Rails API part: http://ember.vicramon.com/

Comment: Thanks, I've actually worked through this whole tutorial and created the app, I liked it a lot